# Controller's actions names localization

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, localization

I am facing a problem.
I would like to localize my action names in my project so french people can have clean urls with french names.

http://www.test.com/Home should be http://www.test.com/Accueil

It is a good thing too for google indexing.
Moreover I would like to be Restful on the application, so I would like too keep english name because developers (even frenchies) prefer to work on english names.

I don't know if it's possible and how.

My first idea should be something like get the browser language, assign it to the CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, so I can select the view name I want.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this when you register the routes in global.asax.

if normally you have this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Catalog-Brands", "catalog/brand/", new {controller = "Brand", action = "Index", isActive = true});
```

you could make this one too (I don't know french, sorry)

```
routes.MapRoute("Catalog-Brands-French", "french-catalog/french-brand/", new {controller = "Brand", action = "Index", isActive = true});
```

you could either make them all available globally or have separate:

```
public static void RegisterUsRoutes

public static void RegisterFrenchRoutes
```

you'd have to make the decision at application startup though (you may or may not be able to register routes at runtime.)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use ISAPIs, that is to say, if you control IIS, the best thing is to use a ISAPI I recommend you Ionics Isapi:
http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF

It implements more or less what Rewrite mod in Apache does (redirections).